# Find the spectrum and resolvent of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the spectrum and resolvent of an operator $$ A \in B(C[-\pi, \pi]), \; \; Ax(t) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi cos(t+s)x(s) ds$$
found that the dot spectrum will look like {-pi, 0, pi}. Will there be other components in the spectrum?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $A$ has rank $2$ so it is compact.